# Marmalade: change screen orientation when video is playing

Tags: rotation, screen, marmalade

In my project (using the Marmalade SDK), I have fixed the screen orientation to portrait in the .icf file. When a user touches a button, a video plays (using s3e video). However, This video is also played in portrait mode (which is not conducive to viewing), and I want the screen to automatically rotate to landscape and have the video take up the entire screen when the button is pressed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the s3eSurface API: http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/group__surfaceapigroup.html#ga70a312268193e75b29451da071c87ead

I guess something like s3eSurfaceSetInt (S3E_SURFACE_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LOCK,  S3E_SURFACE_LANDSCAPE) before playing your video and the same with S3E_SURFACE_PORTRAIT will do the trick :)